# Not able to use class by adding dependency in pom.xml until the jar is added in Java Build Path

Tags: hibernate, spring, maven

I am creating a project using maven with spring and hibernate. I added a dependency for using javax.persistence package in pom.xml like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding this dependency tried to import the package javax.persistence but it didn't showed up. I then downloaded the jar file from mvnrepository related to that and then was able to obviously import the package. I guess, Maven handles the dependency and there should not have been any neccessity of downloading the jar and then adding it to the build path.

Can someone explain where I went wrong?

The .project file has the below content :

```
<projectDescription>
    <name>SampleWebApp</name>
    <comment>This is the sample web app. NO_M2ECLIPSE_SUPPORT: Project files created  with the maven-eclipse-plugin are not supported in M2Eclipse.</comment>
    <projects/>
    <buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
    </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
  <natures>
   <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
  </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: This sounds like an IDE Maven integration problem. What do you mean by not able to import? In an IDE? Please add more detail.

Comment: It shows error if I write javax.persistence.Column import statement. I mean to say any import statement which has javax.persistence as package.

Comment: I am facing the same issue when using SessionFactory class. The dependency for hibernate is already added in pom.xml but when using SessionFactory class it says SessionFactory cannot be resolved.

Comment: What shows an error? Your IDE or a mvn install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the issue was but after deleting the project and creating another one with archetype set to spring it ran successfully. I did read that there some conflicts with m2eclipse and maven-eclipse-plugin. Now, the issue seems to be resolved for now.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this command in the directory where the pom lives:

```
mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

Then refresh your project (right click on project > refresh)

The `mvn eclipse:eclispe` build target creates a `.project` file, which contains the corrected build path entries

Comment: I have edited the message above and mentioned the .project file contents. It seems there is some issue with M2Eclipse plugin that I have configured.